# Copying Data From a Container of one azure Account to Container of another azure account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure and I want to copy a data of container from one azure container to another container. (**Note: The container are in two different azure accounts**). I have a ready only access to the source container and the destination one is my own container so i have a full access to it. The owner of source container claims to allow only one specific ip to access the resource of container.
So which approach should i use?
a) Data Factory
b) Azure Function
c) Az copy

I tried using data factory but i got stuck while linking the service. I was able to link the storage of same account but could not link to storage of completely different account. I tried using SAS to link the service but it keeps giving 403 issue. I also tried writing python script but whenever i try to upload to destination container, it gives resource not found issue.

Comment: 'The owner of source container claims to allow only one specific ip to access the resource of container' - that means you have access to only specific IP addresses right?

Comment: They will whitelist one specific ip from destination. (we have to provide that ip to them)

Comment: I think you can provide the IP address of system from where your ADF is running, so that you can access it from your ADF.

Comment: Does ADF support linking of service from two different account?

Comment: 403 points to an authorization problem. Make sure you are invited as guest. There are several things you can do or cannot do while you are going cross-tenant or multi account, you cannot share SHIR for example. These links may help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/948603/how-may-i-access-a-blob-container-from-another-sub   /

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/29478/is-cross-tenant-blob-access-possible-in-azure   /

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-storage-blog/enable-secure-access-to-azure-storage-account-across-multiple/ba-p/2268550

Comment: To copy a file from one Azure Blob to another, you can use the AzCopy command-line tool. Simply request the owner of the source storage account to provide you with a read access Shared Access Signature (SAS) and whitelist the public IP address of your local machine from which you will be running the AzCopy command.

Comment: I tried using az but it is raising issue(RESPONSE Status: 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)


`azcopy copy 'https://sourcestorage.blob.core.windows.net/sourcecontiner?sastoken' 'https://destinationstorage.blob.core.windows.net/destinationcontainer?sastoken' --recursive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10):

Firstly on Source account files:

[image]

Then used below command:

```
azcopy copy 'https://sourcestorage.blob.core.windows.net/sourcecontiner?sastoken' 'https://destinationstorage.blob.core.windows.net/destinationcontainer?sastoken' --recursive
```

With below permissions:

On Source Blob:

[image]

On Destination Blob:

[image]

I received Same Error as below:

Output:

[image]

Then I gave all permissions on Source and blob as below:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Then in Destination Storage Account:

[image]

Comment: I do not have access to the source container. It belongs to someone else and they will only allow the read only access.

Comment: With Read-Only access you will get 403 error. I guess this will solve your question here. Now its the issue with permissions.

Comment: Or else you need ```Read and List``` https://i.imgur.com/QmiGAxM.png Permissions on Storage Account After giving this 2 then Output is  https://i.imgur.com/2qNxvPM.png. So try them asking for list permission also with which you can copy. You need **Read and list** Permission to copy any file from storage account to another using any  method(azcopy or logicapps, functions, python sdks)(it doesnt depend on methods its only depends on Permissions)

Comment: @RithwikBojja Thankyou! It worked. I also want to make sure it does not copy the whole container again and again. How to perform an incremental copy of it?

Comment: It would be good and feasable if you open a new question for further doubts